# A physics approach to the Jordan curve theorem.

Tags: algebraic-topology, differential-topology

The Jordan curve theorem states that if $f:S^1\to \mathbb R^2$ is an injective continuous function then $\mathbb R^2\setminus \text{image}(f)$ has two connected components. I want to discuss an approach to proving this theorem which is as follows.

Let us instead try to prove the following. Let $f:S^1\to S^2$ be an injective continuous function.
Then $S^2\setminus \text{image}(f)$ has two connected components.

We have $f$ depicted in the following figure in pink.

[image]

Now thinking of $S^2$ as the surface of Earth, and thinking of the iamge of $f$ as a massive string.
We endow the image of $f$ with a uniform positive charge density so that the string starts moving (since it is repelling itself). To keep the string from flying off the planet let us also switch on gravity.
[image]
This should homotope the image of $f$ into a perfect circle. Now one would need to prove that the number of components that any intermediate curve (during gravity assisted homotopy) partitions the sphere into does not change with time, whence the Jordan curve theorem (for the sphere) can be proved since the number of components induced by the final curve is clearly $2$.

I guess one should be able to define an energy function of the system and show that the system has the tendency to go towards the lowest energy configuraton. This configuration shuld be the one where the pairwsie distances of the charges is the greatest, which happens when the string is a perfect circle.
Of course, there would be many technical problems along the way.

I do not know if a proof of the Jordan curve theorem already exists along these lines. If not, then I think a proper execution of this idea should make for a publication.

EDIT:
Thanks to copperhat for pointing out a flaw in the previous post where there was no mention of an electric field.

Comment: A related topic is the curve shortening flow: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curve-shortening_flow

Comment: Why will the string move when you 'switch on gravity'?

Comment: @copper.hat You are right. There is not reason it should. Let us also switch on an electric field. Let me edit.

Comment: I'm a theoretical physicist so it pains me to say this but.... any "physics" proof that says "and is clearly 2" is probably not a sufficiently detailed "proof". Believe me, I wish it were.

As someone else said - you need to make sure the force you impart does the flow you want. Gravity won't flow the string to the equator. Does the string have tension? That would shrink it down smoothly.

Comment: @AlphaNumeric The 'clearly' partis not a problem as long as one can show that the final conguration is a perfect circle. Yes, gravity along does not do the trick. I for some reason thought that it should move the string but that was clearly not the case. I have now made the assumption that there is a uniform positive chare density on the string which would make it move.

Comment: Please, clarify what you mean by "We endow the image of  with a uniform positive charge density": The curve $f$ can be nowhere differentiable.

Comment: What I had in mind was taking the push forward $f_*\lambda$ of the Lebesgue measure $\lambda$ on $S^1$. But I think it is alright to first work with smooth $f$ and then worry about the continuous case. I realize that there already is a not so complicated proof of the Jordan curve theorem for smooth curves but my main point is to get it via this new approach. This may also help prove the the two components are open discs (at least in the smooth case).

Comment: Yes, smooth case is much easier than the case of topological embeddings. As for your approach, most likely, it will be hard to prove that there are no non-round stationary points for your flow. Regardless, it will be surely much harder than standard proofs in the smooth case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This proposal appears to be similar to the idea of the gradient flow of a knot energy, see

*Simon Blatt*, [**The gradient flow of O’Hara’s knot energies**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/s00208-017-1540-4), Math. Ann. 370, No. 3-4, 993-1061 (2018). [ZBL1398.53071](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:1398.53071).

(O'Hara's knot energies are certain regularizations of the energy given by the electrostatic potential.)

In his paper Blatt proves that, given a smooth knot in $S^3=R^3\cup \{\infty\}$, the gradient flow converges to critical points of the energy functional. If I understand this correctly, in the case of an unknot, the only critical points are round circles. (The trouble is that there are so many different versions of the knot energy that I cannot keep track which of these satisfy this uniqueness property.) In particular, this applies to knots contained in round spheres $S^2\subset S^3$. In view of the reflection symmetry, if you apply the gradient flow to a knot contained in a round sphere, the flow will be contained in that sphere.

This is all interesting for its own sake and for the sake of potential applications of the knot theory (say, to study DNA and protein folding), but should not be used in order to prove Jordan Curve theorem for smooth curves, since the latter has a very easy proof using transversal intersections with rays.   None of these will work for topological Jordan curves.